# Display popup when clicking link and adjusting position

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a little popup next to a link on my page. I need this to be dynamic because the number of links generated is random. I want the box to display next to the link each time, so this requires adjusting the position to new coordinates my question is how do I programtically determine where to move the box based on what link is clicked? I am not sure how to approach this and am looking for some suggestions.

HTML

```
<div style="display: none; border: 1px solid black; height: 150px; width: 250px; 
       padding: 5px; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; 
       background-color: silver;" id="messageBox">
    <textarea style="width: 225px; height: 115px;"></textarea>
    <button id="save" style="float: right;">Save</button>
</div>

<div class="productLine">
    <a href="#">Link #1</a><br /><br />
    <a href="#">Link #2</a><br /><br />
</div>
<br />
<div class="productLine">
    <a href="#">Link #3</a><br /><br />
    <a href="#">Link #4</a><br /><br />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.productLine a').click(function() {
    $('#messageBox').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this -  (*you can add width and height of `a` to the left and top to show box at proper position*)

```
$('.productLine a').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#messageBox').css({
        left: $this.position().left + $this.width(),
        top: $this.position().top,
    }).toggle();
});
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/esEP8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use the clicked link's `position().left` and `position().top` to define the popup position. Also it is better to use `on` instead of `click`. Here is the code:

```
$('.productLine').on('click', 'a', function() {
  $('#messageBox').hide().css({
    left: $(this).position().left + $(this).outerWidth(false),
    top: $(this).position().top
  }).show();
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9XTT6/2/